# Getting Default Unselected TintColor of UITabBarItem Image

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

how do we **get** the default color of unselected UITabBarItem Image?

Searched all over SO only returns **methods to change**, while what I want is **only to get** the color.

Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember (I looked into something similar about a year ago) there is no system API to get the "dimmed" colour of inactive controls. I did however reverse engineer the dimming to look relatively similar.

```
public extension UIColor {
    public func dimmedColor() -> UIColor {
        var hue = CGFloat(0)
        var brightness = CGFloat(0)
        var saturation = CGFloat(0)
        var alpha = CGFloat(0)

        self.getHue(&hue, saturation: &saturation, brightness: &brightness, alpha: &alpha)

        brightness = max(0.0, brightness - 0.3)

        return UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: 0, brightness: brightness, alpha: alpha)
    }
}
```

In essence, the dimming desaturates the colour and reduces brightness. This can result in black colours, which might not be what you want though.

You would use this as follows, where `tintColor` is obtained from a UIView or a button or some other tinted element:

```
let dimmedColor = tintColor.dimmedColor()
```

Comment: Interesting answer indeed, but it creates a lighter version than the actual unselected color

Comment: Hmm, I suppose the brightness value I ended up at is not exactly what they use, you could tweak it a bit to see if you get any closer.

Comment: I've tried using different tint colors, that does not affect the unselected color though. it's #929292. I need a way to determine the system color, to anticipate if Apple ever changes the default color

Comment: As I said, from what I know there is now way to do so. You could try to capture the colour, for example by creating a control, letting the system dim it, capturing it in an image and then looking at the colour values.